# Piece-wise function in R

Tags: r, math

I am trying to make a piece-wise function. This is a really basic one. I want y to be a list of values (preferably not just a list of integers but a list of real numbers like (1.34, 20.92) in the future).
How might I make a piece-wise function?

```
y <- 1:10
if (y < 2){
  print("CAN'T COMPUTE")
} else if (y >= 2 & y < 6){
  print(y^2)
} else {
  print(y * 2)
}
```

Comment: You can do something like this `y[y  > 2 & y < 6]`.

Comment: `a<-c(function(x)"CANT COMPUTE",function(x)x^2,function(x)2*x);lapply(1:10, function(y)a[[findInterval(y,c(2,6))+1]](y))`

Answer (score 0):

Let me give it a try:

```
library("dplyr")

y <- 1:10
y %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(res = case_when(y < 2 ~ "CAN'T COMPUTE", 
                         y >= 2 & y < 6 ~ as.character(y^2), 
                         TRUE ~ as.character(y*2)))
```

Here's the results:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   value res          
   <int> <chr>        
 1     1 CAN'T COMPUTE
 2     2 4            
 3     3 9            
 4     4 16           
 5     5 25           
 6     6 12           
 7     7 14           
 8     8 16           
 9     9 18           
10    10 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a some base R approaches.  We have used NA instead of a character string in order to produce a numeric vector result. The first uses a nested ifelse.  The second uses a single ifelse to select between NA and the other values and computes the other values using a formula.  The third computes which leg of the result is wanted (1, 2 or 3) and then uses switch to select that leg.  The fourth is a variation of three that uses findInterval to compute the leg number.

```
ifelse(y < 2, NA, ifelse(y < 6, y^2, 2*y))
## [1] NA  4  9 16 25 12 14 16 18 20

ifelse(y < 2, NA, (y < 6) * y^2 + (y >= 6) * 2*y)
## [1] NA  4  9 16 25 12 14 16 18 20

mapply(switch, 1 + (y >= 2) + (y >= 6), NA, y^2, 2*y)
## [1] NA  4  9 16 25 12 14 16 18 20

mapply(switch, findInterval(y, c(-Inf, 2, 6, Inf), left.open = FALSE), NA, y^2, 2*y)
## [1] NA  4  9 16 25 12 14 16 18 20
```